# Clear activity on top stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have **activity A** and **Activity B**.

**Activity A** start **Activity B** by `intent`. 
After **Activity B** have a event (example event **D**), I make a **listener** to **Activity A** and I want to **Activity A** close **Activity B** because i can't modify Activity B.

What is the solution in my case ?

Thanks,

Comment: Finish activity B with Result_OK, it will send result to Activity A, you can get listener in Activity A.

Comment: Sorry, in my question Activity B have a event not close event. It will make a delegate to Activity A to A see that event have occured and you need close B.

Comment: what is the use case for doing it this way?

Comment: Example I want to close advertisement. AdsActivity, because I can't modify AdsActivity, but I can be known AdsActivity loaded.